# Assigned tags to mails are lost after update to Thunderbird 115

Tags: email, imap, thunderbird

I have updated to Thunderbird version 115 a few days ago and noticed that after the update all tags that I have assigned to mails seem to be lost.

I've used tagging to mark mails as "todo" and "done" and I still can do that after the update. But does anyone know if there is a way to restore previously assigned tags?
It's an exchange mailbox and I think exchange doesn't work with custom tags via IMAP? At least I don't see any of my tags when i view the mailbox via the outlook web client.